# Backbone Marionette Composite view onRender executing twice

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I am having a backbone marionette composite view as follow

```
VideosView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        template : videosTpl,
        id : "video",
        itemView : VideoView,

        initialize : function() {
                 //fetching the collection 
            var myVideos = new VideoCollection();
            myVideos.fetch();
            this.collection = myVideos;
        },
        appendHtml : function(collectionView, itemView) {
            //appending each videos to the video list
            console.log("appendHtml");
            collectionView.$("ul").append(itemView.el);

        },
        onRender: function(){
            console.log("onRender");

        },
        onShow: function(){
            console.log("onShow");

        }
    });
```

The output in the console is

> - onRender
> - onShow
> - 4 appendHtml
> - onRender

The expected code flow according to backbone marionette was

> - 4 appendHtml
> - onRender
> - onShow

How this happen?

Comment: I've seen this happen when you create VideosView before the document loads. Try creating VideosView on document.ready

Comment: i have used require js and the view is loading on document.ready .

Comment: Oh ok. Try stepping through the code using the un-minified Backbone.js code and see which object is triggering the event.

Comment: There was a bug in a old relase of Backbone Marionette 1.0.0 beta. Which version are you using actually? I suggest you to update to the last release anyway.

Comment: updated to the last release. but the error still persist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That may be because you are fetching the data in the initialize function? A fetch cause a collection.reset() and so your Composite view will be re-rendered as stated in the documentation:

"The model and collection for the composite view will re-render themselves under the following conditions:

- When the collection's "reset" event is fired, it will only re-render the collection within the composite, and not the wrapper template..."

In fact when you assign to `this.collection` the value of `myVideos` you are not guaranteed that `fetch()` has done its job, due to the async nature of Javascript.

Try something like that when you call VideosView:

```
var myVideos = new VideoCollection();

myVideos.fetch({success:function(){

    var View = new VideosView({collection:myVideos});
}});
```

Of course now you can blank out your initialize function.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Marionette are you using? There was a bug that caused this in v1.0.0-beta1: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/287

it was fixed in v1.0.0-beta2 (latest release is v1.0.0-beta3 as of writing this)